# How to run npm scripts in VScode using "show all commands" rather than click in the sidebar?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, npm-scripts

Is there any way to run npm scripts using VSCode "show all commands"

```
shift + command + p （in macOS）
```

rather than click in the sidebar, I want to run npm scripts in VSCode all by keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add npm support to VSCode by installing this extension : [npm by egamma](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.vscode-npm-script)

You can then run your npm scripts using the `CTRL+R SHIFT+R` keyboard shortcut. Ie you press `CTRL+R` and then `Shift+R`

[image: npm run]

It will show you all the scripts you have configured in your `package.json`
[image: npm scripts]